# Is this the correct way to model a relationship in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am creating a relationship between sales and products(itens) of sale in Firebase. In Products in the sale I put the key of the sale. As mentioned in json below . Thus this correct?

```
{
    "-KErFwTKVh5hC2XTY1R2": {
        "item": "item",
        "sale_id": "-KErDCSnVK_kyY7Yy0ax",
        "price": 10.99,
        "qty": 70
    }
}, "sale": {
    "-KErDCSnVK_kyY7Yy0ax": {
        "cliente": "sem_cliente",
        "cond-pagamento": "a vista",
        "data": 1460141613687,
        "status": "Pendente"
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Tks , 

"products-in-sale" : {
    "-KErFwTKVh5hC2XTY1R2" : {
      "item" : "item",
      "sale_id" : "-KErDCSnVK_kyY7Yy0ax",
      "price" : 10.99,
      "qty" : 70
    }
  },
  "sale" : {
    "-KErDCSnVK_kyY7Yy0ax" : {
      "cliente" : "sem_cliente",
      "cond-pagamento" : "a vista",
      "data" : 1460141613687,
      "status" : "Pendente"
    }
  }
}

Comment: In a NoSQL database you often model for your data for the way your application needs to consume it. So there is no single correct way to model it. I recommend reading this article on [NoSQL Data Modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) to get a better starting point for working with data modeling for Firebase (and other NoSQL databases).

Comment: Thank you, my biggest problem is how to unite in a query all sales and items through sale_id . As example -KErDCSnVK_kyY7Yy0ax .